# Problem with 'copy-paste' and 'shared folders' in VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, shared-folders, guest-additions

I have Windows 7 as the host OS, VirtualBox 5.0.2 and Ubuntu 14.04 as a guest OS.

Right after I install Ubuntu the window resize works correctly, but I can't use 'copy-paste' and 'shared folders' functionality. As I knew from the Internet, in order to enable needed functions I have to use 'VirtualBox Guest Additions'.

I tried to install this from the menu (Devices->Insert Guest Additions CD image) and via the Terminal. Anyway, after the Guest Additions were installed I've got 'copy-paste' and 'shared folders' functions working, but the window resizing is now broken.

Could you, please, help me with this issue?

**Solution:**

Hm, the problem solved... unexpectedly: I reinstalled the guest OS, rebooted it, installed the Guest Additions from the menu and installed the system updates, that appeared in the unity menu (without the system reboot between the Additions and updates installation), and then rebooted the system. That helped - the 'window resize', 'copy-paste' and 'shared folders' functions are currently working simultaneously. Profit!

Comment: The virtual guest graphics adapter may have not installed correctly. Did you get any error messages on installing the guest additions? Did you reboot the guest OS?

Comment: @Takkat, there where no error messages during the installation process, and of course I restarted the guest machine.

Comment: Sometimes just reinstalling the guest additions helps. Did you tick the auto-resize option from VBox manager?

Comment: @Takkat, yes, I tried to reinstall the guest additions, and ticked all display options from the VBox manager.

Comment: @lujewwy Please post your solution as an answer instead of part of the question. See https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer for details.

Comment: @lujewwy Post the solution as an answer so others can benefict from that. You can answer your own question, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, the problem solved... unexpectedly: I reinstalled the guest OS, rebooted it, installed the Guest Additions from the menu and installed the system updates, that appeared in the unity menu (without the system reboot between the Additions and updates installation), and then rebooted the system. That helped - the 'window resize', 'copy-paste' and 'shared folders' functions are currently working simultaneously. Profit!